# Adding multiple values of the same scoreboard to a target slector

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, what I want to make is a randomizer that constantly runs from 0-100 (which I already have) that at certain values swaps one mob with another. Simulating natural spawning for the mob. (It's for an RPG-ish special enemy system) So I have the whole thing done, but the issue is that I can't select multiple values of the same scoreboard: `@e[scores={randomizer=1,randomizer=50,randomizer=99}]` is supposed to summon the mob at three points (which is about 3% spawn chance), however they will only spawn at 99(only 1%). Does anyone know an answer to this that is NOT `@e[scores={randomizer=0..20}]` for 20% spawn chance, because this causes them to spawn in big groups at once.

If you'd want to know, the randomizer is an armor_stand with a specific name.
Here's the exact command used for one of the mobs:

```
execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name="randomizerdummy",scores={randomizer=0,randomizer=5**(so on to 100, for the sake of saving some space)**}] run
    execute as @e[limit=1,sort=arbitrary,type=iron_golem,scores={lifetime=0..2},name=!"Peacekeeper"] at @s run
    scoreboard players set @s golemspawn 1
```

*(Note that the above is a single command split over 3 lines to improve readability)*

So it's executed from the armor stand at certain values to one random iron golem with a lifetime(dummy scoreboard that is constantly running) of 0..2

The `name=!"Peacekeeper"` is just to keep it from swapping an already swapped golem

Comment: You're probably going to have to run the command once for each randomizer value you want at a given time.  Can you better articulate why you don't want to use ranges (even small ones that will give the proper spawn chance)?

Comment: So you want to do something if the random value is either 1 or 50 or 99? Why not just 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: Well, the reason that I don't just take 0..20 for example is because if there are skeletons spawning, they usually spawn in groups. And lets say they all spawn when the randomizer is at value 0 at this point. Then one skeleton would be swapped, it the goes to value 1 swapping another skeleton, and once more for value 2 (because the lifetime of 0..2) causing three of them to spawn within 0,1s. Although now that I think of it that may have led to answer my own question...
Because I can just change the randomizer value to 0..20 and the lifetime value check to 0..0 causing it to only spawn one...

Comment: Your problem might be because I think only one score condition per objective is allowed. You said you did "scores={randomizer=0,randomizer=50,randomizer=99}". My theory is that it is ignoring all the score conditions before randomizer=99. Perhaps a solution would be to tag all skeletons with those scores and then target them with tag=<the tag you use>.